# Start subprocess with classpath in Spring results in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, subprocess, classnotfoundexception

I have an application that starts another class in a subprocess via Java's internal `java.lang.ProcessHandler`. Quite simple:

```java
public MySubProcessHandler() {
        // setup commands
        String javaHome = System.getProperty(ProcessKeys.JAVA_HOME);
        String javaBin = Paths.get(javaHome, "bin", "java").toString();
        String classpath = System.getProperty(ProcessKeys.JAVA_CLASSPATH);
        String className = MyServer.class.getName();

        List<String> command = new LinkedList<>();
        command.add(javaBin);
        command.add("-classpath");
        command.add(classpath);
        command.add(className);

        // setup sub process
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        processBuilder.start();
}
```

Now everything works fine within this application and also in IntelliJ.
But, I use this within a Spring-Boot application too. When I start the executable JAR and want to create the subprocess the error-stream of that subprocess sends me:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class my.path.to.MyServer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.path.to.MyServer
```

When I check the executable jar from the Spring application, it indeed only consists of the internal project classes but without the dependencies. The dependencies are in `BOOT-INF/lib/my-server.jar`

**Question:** What can I do that Spring loads this class so that `MySubProcessHandler` is able to find it?

*My Current Approaches:* First, I thought I may hack around this by setup `MyServer` as a `@Bean` in order to force Spring to load the class. Unfortunately, it didn't seem to work. I found that IntelliJ automatically adds the dependant maven repositories to the classpath when starting the application and that solves the problem! So with IntelliJ it works nicely. However, considering the needed jar (with the "missing" class) is already in the fat jar, it looks wrong to manually add the maven dependency to the classpath on startup. There must be another solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out, Spring is using a different way to start (in spring the terminology is launching) or load classes. This is nicely explained in [Spring's doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html) about "*The Executable Jar Format*".

Usually, one can start the main class directly via the following command:

```
java -cp my-project.jar my.path.to.MyServer
```

But if `my-project.jar` is an executable JAR from Spring, one need to use Spring's `PropertiesLauncher` for loading and *launching*. You can do this via:

```
java -cp my-spring-project.jar \
   -Dload.main=my.path.to.MyServer \
   org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

So this simply starts a JVM via spring boot and loads the given main class via Spring's `PropertiesLauncher`. Updating the code for `MySubProcessHandler()` from above according to this command fixes the issue.